# Can't insert COLUMNS in Excel 2013 - No Tables, No Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel

I attempted to insert 2 columns in my spreadsheet, but I got the error message:

> This operation is not allowed. The operation is attempting to shift cells in a table on your worksheet.

I have not merged or hidden any cells/rows/columns. There are no formulas. There are no tables.  I reviewed all other Q&A on this site to no avail.  I tried closing and re-opening the spreadsheet.

Note: I am able to insert rows.

Comment: Select and clear contents. You've inserted a Table with special formatting into your worksheet; you can't insert columns without screwing up the formatting.

Comment: It really does sound like there's a table on your sheet. If you go up to the name box in the upper left (next to the formula bar, where it shows you the address of the currently active cell) and click on the down arrow to the right of the cell address, a dropdown list will open. Are there any entries in that list, or is it just blank?

Comment: @Kat Can you tell us if you tried the recommendations and if you have any results

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing CTRL+6 on the keyboard (using the 6 above "T Y").  This will cycle between three display modes: hiding objects, displaying objects, and displaying placeholders for objects.

I have the problem you describe from time to time and this always works for me.  It normally happens when I have an image or a chart embedded on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to fix this is to clear the copied contents by cutting and pasting any cell. So you now have nothing copied. Then right click the column again and select insert. This will insert a blank column, then paste the contents you want into it.

Sadly in excel it always has issues with copy and paste more than one cell.